# How rewrite COUNT DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a problem with only one reducer in hive, because of using count and distinct in one query.
How to rewrite select to eliminate this? Is it possible in window functions?

```
 select
  a.second_id,
  if(a.proc_id = 'CONST1' and bb.third_id is not null,
     count(distinct bb.first_id),
     '') as qty
from a          a
join (select
        b.first_id,
        b.second_id,
        b.third_id
      from b b) bb
     on bb.second_id = a.second_id
group by
  a.second_id,
  a.proc_id,
  bb.third_id;
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select a.second_id,
       (case when a.proc_id = 'CONST1' and bb.third_id is not null
             then count(distinct bb.first_id)
        end) as qty
from a join
     (select b.first_id, b.second_id, b.third_id
      from b
     ) bb
     on bb.second_id = a.second_id
group by a.second_id, a.proc_id, bb.third_id;
```

The `count(distinct)` can really be handled in the subquery, using `group by` and window functions.  I don't see any value to not aggregating first, so:

```
select a.second_id,
       (case when a.proc_id = 'CONST1' and bb.third_id is not null
             then max(bb.num_firsts)
        end) as qty
from a join
     (select b.second_id, b.third_id,
             count(distinct first_id) as num_firsts
      from b
      group by b.second_id, b.third_id
     ) bb
     on bb.second_id = a.second_id
group by a.second_id, a.proc_id, bb.third_id;
```

You are aggregating by `second_id` and `third_id` in the outer query.  So there is only one row from the aggregated subquery in the outer query.  The above version uses `max(first_id)`, but you could also include `num_firsts` in the outer `group by`.

That still might not fix your problem, but this query is easier to modify.  If I recall, the best approach in Hive is a `select distinct` subquery:

```
select a.second_id,
       (case when a.proc_id = 'CONST1' and bb.third_id is not null
             then max(bb.num_firsts)
        end) as qty
from a join
     (select b.second_id, b.third_id,
             count(*) as num_firsts
      from (select distinct second_id, third_id, first_id
            from b
           ) b
      group by b.second_id, b.third_id
     ) bb
     on bb.second_id = a.second_id
group by a.second_id, a.proc_id, bb.third_id;
```

This is the same thing if `first_id` is never `null`.  This will count that as a separate value; if you don't want to, just filter them out.